# Understading mysql_real_escape_string();

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I don't understand why `mysql_real_escape_string` needs to escape new line and carriage return chars:

`\n` and `\r`

What could be the security holes in a sql with `\n` and `\r` ?

```
UPDATE tbl SET field = 'text text text \n text text text \r text text' WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn’t require the newline character to be escaped. The [manual page for the `mysql_real_escape_string` function of MySQL’s C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) says:

> Characters encoded are “`\`”, “`'`”, “`"`”, `NUL` (ASCII 0), “`\n`”, “`\r`”, and Control+Z. Strictly speaking, MySQL requires only that backslash and the quote character used to quote the string in the query be escaped. `mysql_real_escape_string()` quotes the other characters to make them easier to read in log files.

Comment: So basically mysql requires only backslash and quote to be escaped. So considering i am using always utf-8 i don't need to use `mysql_real_escape_string();` I just need to escape `\ ` and `'`

Comment: Theoretically, yes. But I would advise against doing it manually. Better use some technique that does this automatically like parameterized queries or prepared statements.

Comment: there was an aswer where someone explained why it's important to use real_escape_string with UTF-8 (there was a char that could case problem) can't find atm

Comment: I think you mean [this issue with a certain character in GBK](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) – that’s not related to UTF-8. But again, manual escaping can lead to carelessness. That’s why you should rather use parameterized queries or prepared statements.